# Unaligned images with text underneath? CSS / HTML

Tags: html, css

[unaligned images and text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPqig.png)

I have attempted to input suggestions from previous questions but it just seems I have been able to successfully find the correct way to align these images with their text underneath.

```
<section id="boxes">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <img src="./images/dayporter2.jpeg">
            <h3>DAYPORT</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed 
               do eiusmod
               tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">   
            <img src="./images/floorcare1.jpeg">
            <div class="box">
            <h3>FLOOR CARE</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed 
               do eiusmod
               tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="./images/janitor2.jpeg">
    </div>
</section>

/* boxes */


#boxes{
    margin-top: 20px;
}


#boxes .box{
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 10px;
 }

 #boxes .box img{
    width: 90px;
 }`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <div class="box">   
        <img src="./images/floorcare1.jpeg">
        <div class="box"> <!-- The probleme is here -->
            <h3>FLOOR CARE</h3>
```

Because the `.box` element which is direct below the image is float left, it will force the image to be float left, because their sibling `.box` take 30% of the parent and there are remaining 70% width of their `.box` parent element. You must remove the `.box` element and every thing will work like you expecting. 
Another problem you must close all you open markup

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <!-- First box -->
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <!-- Second box -->
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <!-- Third box -->
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thorough explanation, it helped a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. Can you ancept the answer and up vote

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have an unnecessary div tag.

remove the div tag after your 'floorcare1.jpeg' img, here:

```
<img src="./images/floorcare1.jpeg">
            <div class="box"> //remove this
```